# Transaction failed. The server response was: SMTP Host

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient

I've been trying to make a simple eMail sending APP and I'm blocked with this error, I can't seem to find anyone with this problem (Kinda clueless of what to search though)

So I'm having this error when I try to send my eMail, it just returns me this error with the name of my SMTP Host,

> Transaction failed. The server response was: smtp.host.com

If I look at the trace it crashes at

> at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)

Here's the code sample, nothing fancy.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress(CurrentUser.email);
mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
mail.Body = txtMailBody.Text;

try
{
    foreach (ListItem user in lbSelectedUsr.Items)
    { 
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(user.email));
    }

    SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.host.com");
    mailClient.Send(mail);

    lblResultOK.Visible = true;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    lblResultOK.Visible = true;
}
```

Note that the SMTP is fake for the sake of the sample.

I tried with invalid SMTP and it gave me different error so the SMTP seems to be OK, 
I also tried to put credentials, same error. Any hint on what's happening?

Comment: are  you using exchange?  and if so, is the server set to accept relay from the ip address where you are running the code?  Also make sure that the email addresses are coming across as valid.  Try taking the foreach loop out and hardcoding on "to address" and also hardcoding a dummy from address and see if it works then.  that will eliminate the addresses as the problem.   You can also try the IP address of the mail server rather than the host name.

Comment: I think I'm with exchange, I've been switched to that new project and I'm quite confused in it, I'll ask around, but I recall having my computer some problem connecting to the Local server, so that might be the problem. I did put hardcode emails on "To" and "From" still the same result. I'm not sure if I can find the IP address of the mail server, we're using the SMTP of our internet Host.

Comment: Ok, we were using the wrong SMTP apparently, we're with Bell (Sympatico) and we are trying to use their Open SMTP server (Not Auth required) which is supposed to be: smtp1.sympatico.ca, but it gives me and even more obscure error which is. {"Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."}

Comment: sounds like the issue is with your smtp server not accepting the request to send the email

Comment: Client side SMTP error messages are intentionally vague. If you want to find out what the actual problem is without spending endless hours on trial-and-error, 
 you'll need to contact the postmaster or admin for the server that isn't talking to you and ask him/her to check the server logs. You might get some extra information if you dump the entire ex object in your exception handler.

Comment: @JsGarneau, Did you solve your problem ? Please share us the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I your SMTP config set properly in Web.Config file? 
I would say try to send a sample email via host="smtp.gmail.com"

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="emailAddress">
    <network host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="emailAddress" password="password" defaultCredentials="false"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Comment: As stated above, it worked fine via Google. The problem really feels like it's coming from our SMTP.

Answer (score 1):

Below code must be placed in web.config. The attention point is defaultCredentials="false"

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="aaa@yourdomain.com">
    <network host="mail.yourdomain.com" userName="aaa@yourdomain.com" password="your password" port="587" defaultCredentials="false"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try send by google smtp, and if every one is ok then change it to your smtp server info.If you do it and If your problem is still in place,  then you must check your smtp server.

- This is a good start point: ([GMailMailSender.zip](http://www.programmerfish.com/downloads/GmailMailSender.zip))
- And read its tutorial, [here](http://www.programmerfish.com/send-email-using-gmail-in-aspnet-c/)

Comment: Ok, it worked with Google's SMTP. I'll check for my SMTP then.

Answer (score 0):

The server does not accept relay from the machine that runs your app. Configure the server appropriately, or run the code on the machine that is already configured for relay (usually all computers within the domain; I suppose that your computer belongs to a different domain than SMTP server).

Answer (score 0):

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress(CurrentUser.email);
mail.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
mail.Body = txtMailBody.Text;

try
{
    foreach (ListItem user in lbSelectedUsr.Items)
    { 
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(user.email));
    }

    SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.host.com");
    mailClient.EnableSsl = true
    mailClient.Send(mail);

    lblResultOK.Visible = true;
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    lblResultKO.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: try this if your Server has Credential then you should Passed Credential using mailClient.NetworkCredential("UserName","Password") after SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("abc.host.com");

Comment: Your answer is a copy of the code sample provided in the question. Please edit your answer if you want to include the information from your comment.